# Reading JSON from AJAX call. Values in JSON of 0.00 are interpreted as 0 in Javascript. How to display them correctly?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an AJAX call to the database which is returning JSON output

When I look in the network response from the AJAX call, I can see the JSON correctly formatted:
`..."costhaulage":260.00,"costtonnage":0.00,"includedtonnage":0.0,...`

When I use the console to view the returned data object, it looks like this

```
...
costhaulage: 260
costtonnage: 0
includedtonnage: 0
...
```

When displaying these values to the user (using dynamic HTML) I need to maintain the formatting with any appropriate leading zero to two decimal places, as it was returned in the JSON header, but instead I get the 'unformatted' version.

What is the best/accepted way of displaying currency data in dynamic html so that when it gets set by javascript is is formatted as required?

Comment: You could try something along `(260.35345).toFixed(2)` (`costhaulage.toFixed(2)`) when rendering the values.

Comment: This has done the trick. I did not know that `toFixed(2)` would implicitly force the 0 before the decimal if the value is 0. Please submit as an answer.

Comment: If you want any language to be able to pick up the ".00" from your api call, those values need to be strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to achieve is to use the `onFixed` method.

**Example:**

```
costhaulage.toFixed(2)
```